# Finishing activities A & B from activity B and go to activity C in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activity in my android app: login, Main, user.

First, my app start with login, then go to Main (I call "login.this.finish();")
In Main activity i have a button to go to user activity without finish Main, and in user activity i have "logout" button.

I want to finish Main activity and user activity and go to login activity when user press the "logout" button, how can i do that.

Any one can help me please, and thanks for you all.

Comment: Simply create an intent when user logs out?

Comment: define an intent with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`

Comment: no, it doesn't go back

Comment: where i should to define it, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better solution is, you should replace startActivity() with startActivityForResult() for activity transition. And from logout userActivity you just set a result and you will get onActivityResult in your mainActivity if you handle it properly.Then you can simply finish mainActivity.

Refer **https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html**

Another way is finish MainActivity from its onResume, if the activity onResume is called after logout from userActivity.

Comment: Thank you so much,  I try it and it work perfectly ^_^

Answer (score 0):

start activity again and use System.exit

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your information is new to me, and i have learned new thing (:

Answer (score 0):

The best way, I think is:

```
public void showLogin(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);
        ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
        Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
        activity.startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
```

But, you need to add android support library to your project.
Also, you can try to make logout using intent flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP:

```
public void showLogin(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

It usually works, but not always.

Comment: Thank you for your help. (: